# Socket.io: chat application message positions

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i have socket.io chat application with rooms but without usernames, everything works except this: before i hosted my site, i was testing it in my browser and i was using `document.hasFocus()` method for design chat messages like this [image] and my code was like this

```
 if (!document.hasFocus()) {

        var mess = data.message;
        var encod = $('<div />').text(mess).html();
        output.innerHTML += '<div class="hisout"><p class="me">' + encod +
            '</p></div>'

        output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight
```

and otherwise div's class inside my output div would be myout

it worked in my browser while testing and also working during production but not with 2 different devices, it was causing weird things like my partner's messages was displayed as mine (often) so does anyone know solve for this problem ? here is my server side code

```
 socket.on('chat', function(data) {

 chnm.in(socket.current_room).emit('chat',data);

 });
```

chnm is chat namespace (io.of('/url'))

thank you

Comment: really? nobody knows?

Comment: how is `document.hasFocus` meant to be a good way to tell if the message is yours or your partners. Seems it would be completely irrelevant.

Comment: yeah i was testing in my browser and it worked in that way, that blinded me and did not realize that it was the biggest bug

Comment: do you know the clue?

Comment: I would expect that the message data would need to include a user id of some form.

Comment: what about socket.id/

Comment: I would expect `data = { user: "user1Id", message: "foo" }` and to use the user prop to identify the sender.

Comment: sorry but this small snippet is kind of unclear can you show me really small snippet SERVER&CLIENT in answer so i will be able to mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to add an owner property to the messages you are sending to the clients. This should come from a session controlled by the server so clients can't spoof other clients, etc. So you would have some form of login which created a server-side session and you would then use that to add a user id to the messages.

Really roughly it might be something like this using express server..

```
const expressSession = require("express-session");
const sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");

const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

const session = expressSession();

// // Share session with io sockets and auto save on change
io.use(sharedsession(session), { autoSave: true });

io.on("connection", socket => {
  const { session } = socket.handshake;
  socket.on('chat', function(data) {
  chnm.in(socket.current_room).emit('chat', { ...data, user: session.userId });
  });
});
```

Comment: what about client how can i determine in client side message owner this is problem for me, server side has many alternative for doing this

Comment: `if (data.user === myId) {`

Comment: oh, i understood but in that case i should pass Id too